# Nextjs <Link> not passing query params when using `as`

Tags: next.js

```
<Link
   href={{
      pathname: "/preview",
      query: {
        title: title,
      },
   }}
 as="/preview"
>
```

I'm trying to pass query params to the `preview` page with the `as` Link property. It doesn't pass them. Without `as` it does, but then the url looks ugly.

I just want to pass params to this preview page while keeping the url as `/preview`.

Any ideas?

If I use `router.push` then it works but then there is no way to open the page in a new tab (it's important for me)...

Comment: Are you using react-router or next.js? You've tagged them both but they have *different* routers with *different* `<Link>` elements!

Comment: Sorry my bad. Next.js only.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. I've been looking for this answer for days now... Thank you for pointing to the right direction.